# Best way to handle paginated data fetched from API

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

So I have an Android and IOS application which both make use of a Core application. There are some services in there where I won't go into detail to because it isn't explaining my point. Anyway, the service returns a `Pagination` object with a `Data` attribute to it.

The `Pagination` model looks likes the following:

```
public class Pagination<T>
{
    public Pagination ()
    {
    }

    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Per_Page { get ; set; }
    public int Current_Page { get; set; }
    public int Last_Page { get; set; }
    public int From { get; set; }
    public int To { get; set; }
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }


}
```

And the data that my API is returning looks like the following:

```
{
    total: 41,
    per_page: 10,
    current_page: 1,
    last_page: 5,
    from: 1,
    to: 10,
    data: [ {} , {} , {} ]
}
```

So the service method that populates the `Pagination` object looks like the following:

```
photoservice.GetPhotos (album.Venue_Id, album.ID, page, (Pagination<Photo> obj) => {
    // Save the objects to the internal SQLite database
    photoManager.SavePhotos(obj.Data);

});
```

And now my questions are:

- How to handle the data that I fetch?
- How to keep state of the pages that already have been fetched?
- How to properly update views when there is more data to fetch?
- Does somebody knows best practices for this?
- How to notify the UI in an elegant way?

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards,
Jack

EDIT:

I realize that the questions I'm asking are to broad. I should zoom in on one of them. So what I really want to know:

- How to keep state of the pages that already have been fetched?

Comment: Please try to ask a single question at a time.  It's difficult to write a helpful response when you ask multiple questions at once.  Some of your questions, like "How to handle the data that I fetch?" are incredibly broad.  You could do lots of things with the data - render it in the UI, store it in a db, etc - that's up to you.

Comment: Edited my question a bit. I would really like to know if you have any recommendations for me.